# Java: What is the difference between addHeader and bodyString

Tags: java, json, api, request, fluent

I'm new to Java and have been looking at a couple of codes for Fluent Request. Most of it made sense except for a tiny bit. In the following code, can I know the difference between `.addHeader("content-type", "application/json")` and `.bodyString(json, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON)`, please. Aren't they both specifying that the content type should be Json?

```
httpResponse = Request.Post(URL)
.addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
.addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
.bodyString(json, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON)
.execute()
.returnResponse();
```

Comment: If you are interested in the source code to see what happens, have a look here : http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.httpcomponents/fluent-hc/4.2/org/apache/http/client/fluent/Request.java

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that setting ContentType in bodystring() adds the "content-type" header itself.
So you would use addHeader("content-type", "application/json") explicitly if you need to send a request that does not contain any body data, otherwise just use bodystring().